# DolphinDB Python API raised exception of closed connection with s.close()

Tags: dolphindb

I got the following error when using s.close(). Does it mean I don’t need to close the script manually?

undef table 'TMP_TBL_8ab853c7' got an exception:
 in run: Couldn't send script/function to the remote host because the connection has been closed

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred because you didn’t cancel local variables’ reference to server-side objects. For example, `tb=s.loadTable("day","dfs://day")`.

Before calling `close()` in DolphinDB, add `tb=None` to cancel the reference.